# Nested subQueries with comparing dates

Tags: mysql, sql

Is this right? I feel like my logic is off here but I need to list students who started later than at least one student enrolled in 'IT' department.

```
SELECT studentid, year
FROM enrolled, course
WHERE program = 'IT' and year >= ALL (
      SELECT year FROM enrolled);


enrolled(studentid, courseID, year)
course(courseid, department)
```

I believe everything is right except the where part

---

Sorry, I gave out the wrong schema, it was suppose to be from

Student(sid, started, program)

but I believe it now works with this, thank you

```
SELECT sid, started
FROM student 
WHERE started > (
  SELECT MIN(started)
  FROM student
  WHERE program = 'IT');
```

Comment: started later than at least "one" student?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take it in steps

The first student to be in "IT" (guessing there is a column named program)

```
SELECT MIN(year)
FROM enrolled
WHERE program = 'IT'
```

List students who started later than at least one student enrolled in 'IT' department.

```
SELECT studentid, year
FROM enrolled 
WHERE year > (
  SELECT MIN(year)
  FROM enrolled
  WHERE program = 'IT'
)
```

Comment: sorry i had given you the wrong schema but i fixed it now. I understand the nested query inside WHERE but I have a hard time wrapping around it since im use to Object Oriented way of thinking. Thanks!